# How to find word 'food2u' by search 'food' in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a rookie who just started learning elasticsearch,And I want to find word like 'food2u' by search keyword 'food'.But I can only get the results like 'Food Repo','Give Food' etc. The field's Mapping is 'text' and this is my query

```
GET api/_search
{"query": {
    "match": {
      "Name": {
        "query": "food"
      }
    }
  },
  "_source":{
        "includes":["Name"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the results like 'Food Repo','Give Food', as the `text` field uses a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) if no analyzer is specified. `Food Repo` gets tokenized into `food` and `repo`. Similarly `Give Food` gets tokenized into `give` and `food`.
But `food2u` gets tokenized into `food2u`. Since there is no matching token ("`food`"), you will not get the `food2u` document.

You need to use [edge_ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) to do a partial text match.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 4,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 10
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "name":"food2u"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "food"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67552800",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "name": "food2u"
        }
      }
    ]
```

---

**If you don't want to change the mapping, you can even use a wildcard query to return the matching documents**

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "Name": {
        "value": "food*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**OR you can even use [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) with wildcard**

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "food*",
      "fields": [
        "Name"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```